# How to get list of Arguments of calling method?

Tags: java, reflection

I have one class named `xyz` which contains 10 methods with different arguments.
Now I want to call runtime method using `Reflection` i.e.

```
Class docClass = Class.forName(this.getClass().getCanonicalName().toString());
Method method = getClass().getDeclaredMethod(requestObject.getMethod().toString());
```

It gives me exception because parameter is not unique out of 10 method 7 contains 1 parameter and 2 takes 2 parameter(arguments) and 1 takes 3 arguments.

Can anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What? Why `Class docClass =Class.forName(this.getClass().getCanonicalName().toString());` instead of `Class docClass = this.getClass()`? And then your next line for `Method` does that... what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Never seen an exception named `bcaz` in Java.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : I am trying to call method from web and it is dynamically call my method but method contains different argument so i need to determine number of argument in calling method]

Comment: You never really used `docClass`. You used `getClass()` instead.

Comment: @Unihedron : its same like if i use docClass.getDeclaredMethod(requestObject.getMethod().toString());

Comment: @SSH Yes it's the same, but then the line for `docClass` initialization is abundant and not used. Also please format code (and special `type`s) with "`" in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getDeclaredMethod` of `Class` takes the name of the method as first parameter, and a varargs of `Class<?>` as `parameterTypes`.

Since it's a varargs, you don't need to specify any argument (just as you do in your question text).

However, not speciying any argument will imply referencing a method that takes no arguments.

You should somewhat add those in your `requestObject` instance, so that you can then represent them as an `array` of `Class<?>`.

It'll be quite tedious as you'll have to iterate with `Class.forName` calls for each (I assume) `String` representation.

However then you'll be able to get the right overload for that method.

Comment: when i check for this consition 'if (documentClass.getDeclaredMethod(requestObject.getMethod().toString(),requestObject.getClass()) != null)' it works fine for single agrument but when method contains 2 agrument then it generate exception like 'NoSuchMethodFound'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `Object callMethod(Object receiver, String methodName, Object... parameters)`. As it happens, I have one I wrote about on my [blog  here](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reflections.html). Mine looks like this,

```
/**
 * <b>Rationale:</b> Provide a mechanism to generically call
 * a method.
 * 
 * @author Elliott Frisch
 */
public class MethodUtil {
  /**
   * Returns the size (or length) of an array.
   * 
   * @param obj
   *          The Array to find the size of .
   * @return The length of the array (if object is an
   *         array), or 0.
   */
  private static int safeSize(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null) {
      return Array.getLength(obj);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  /**
   * If it exists, invoke methodName on receiver - passing
   * parameters (if they exist) as arguments. If
   * receiver.methodName(parameters) returns, return the
   * returned value.
   * 
   * @param receiver
   *          The receiver to invoke.
   * @param methodName
   *          The name of the method to call.
   * @param parameters
   *          The arguments to pass to the method.
   * @return The value returned from invoking methodName on
   *         receiver.
   * @throws Exception
   *           Any Exception thrown by invoking the method
   *           with the passed parameters.
   */
  public static Object callMethod(Object receiver,
      String methodName, Object... parameters)
      throws Exception {
    if (receiver == null || methodName == null) {
      return null;
    }
    methodName = methodName.trim();
    if (methodName.length() == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    Class<?> cls = receiver.getClass();
    Method toInvoke = null;
    outer: for (Method method : cls.getMethods()) {
      if (!methodName.equals(method.getName())) {
        continue;
      }
      Class<?>[] mTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
      if (parameters == null && mTypes == null) {
        toInvoke = method;
        break;
      } else if (safeSize(mTypes) == 0 || safeSize(parameters) == 0) {
        continue;
      } else if (safeSize(mTypes) != safeSize(parameters)) {
        continue;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < mTypes.length; ++i) {
        if (!mTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(parameters[i]
            .getClass())) {
          continue outer;
        }
      }
      toInvoke = method;
      break;
    }
    if (toInvoke != null) {
      try {
        return toInvoke.invoke(receiver, parameters);
      } catch (Exception t) {
        throw t;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * A small sample program. Prints 100. Prints 200.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("99");
      a = (BigDecimal) callMethod(a, "add",
          new BigDecimal("1"));
      System.out.println(a);
      System.out.println(callMethod(a, "multiply",
          new BigDecimal("2")));
      System.out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```